# cannot ssh to raspberry pi - connection refused - How to setup raspberry pi without display?

Tags: ssh

I have new **raspberry pi 2 model B** and it came with NOOBS pre-installed. I don't have display so I connected raspberry pi to Ethernet so that I can connect to it by using my laptop via **ssh**. Both are connected to same network. I tried running these command with no success

```
ssh pi@192.168.2.3 -p 23
ssh pi@192.168.2.3 -p 22
```

**NOTE:** 1. I have scanned the network for IP address and I know the its IP address.
2. I have checked other similar questions on this website but they dont have accepted answer or the answer that helps me.

Or How to setup Raspberry Pi without display?

Comment: Noobs allows you to select an image to install. First boot of Noobs you will need keyboard and monitor. First boot of some images you will need these as well

Comment: Have you tried to shh without the port just using Ssh pi@ip_address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using NOOBS you need to setup it before use, that means you cannot use it without display on first use.
To solve this problem I am using [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), raspbian by default comes with `ssh` enabled. All you need to do is download the image and burn it using image writer and you are good to go.

After you burn the image to SD card, insert it into Raspberry Pi and turn it on by connecting the power source (which is, nowadays, a charger of smart-phones), then connect Ethernet port. You need to have a router with DHCP enabled. Now you have to find the IP address of RP, for that, on Linux distribution, you can use `zenmap` or `nmap`.
After you know the IP address of RP, you can ssh into it from your computer/laptop

```
ssh pi@<IP address>
```

by default, the username is `pi` and password is `raspberry`, here IP address will be local IP address starting with either `192.168.*.*` or `10.*.*.*` or `172.16-31.*.*`

**NOTE:** You cannot use Wifi on first use without display because there is no default settings for it

Comment: `here IP address will be local IP address starting with either 192.168.* or 10.42.0.*` ... **wrong** ... it will be `192.168.*.*` or `10.*.*.*` or `172.16-31.*.*` if you are behind a typical NAT router